# Android Studio: Missing: Emulator Greyed out

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

Background to problem and how it all started:

I suddenly and without warning had errors related to plugins. Specifically, firebase services and firebase testing plugins not enabled. Result, could not open my project.

After lengthy research and struggle I was finally able to enable these plugins (along with others)through a miracle and opened my project BUT a new problem has now emerged.

Now the run app button for the emulator is greyed out. If i try to go to the top and click on: RUN APP ==> the "run green" button is also greyed out here (along with "debug" and "Run with coverage".

When I open a recent project in Android Studio in a new window the emulator run button is visible and I can open the Emulator without any problems. It's only suddenly this one project. It's been working just fine until now.

I updated Android Studio just prior to this as it requested it. I am using Android Studio 2.2.1.

Any suggestions highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Actually by stroke of luck I found a solution and it worked perfectly. For anyone else that has this problem the solution is found on Youtube at below link. Thanks to the uploader of this video. Saved my day!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1ApErUGZ_M

Comment: post this as an answer, so others can easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that has this problem the solution is found on Youtube at below link. Thanks to the uploader of this video. Saved my day!

youtube.com/watch?v=o1ApErUGZ_M

Answer (score 0):

Its weird but it worked.
Just deselect and select again those two plugins .
Click Ok.
It will prompt for restart. Click Restart.
It works!